# Critique: Does this logo portray a web-based control for a media player?

Tags: icon, logo, critique

I've been working on an application that works as a remote control for a media player, over the web.
The remote itself is an application that runs in your web browser, on your phone or on your tablet that allows you to control the playlist, playback and library management of a media player.
My logo idea for it was to merge the **Wi-Fi icon with a compact disc**, and below is the render:

[image: Product Logo; Blue Wi-Fi icon merged with Compact Disc]

I've been spending far too long staring at this now, and I think that it works quite well as a concept. However I feel that the colours could be chosen better, but I did receive comments that it looked a little like Spotify's icon when green.

Any critiques?

After reviewing suggestions, I have come up with this:

[image: Updated Product Logo; Blue Wi-Fi icon merged with Compact Disc]

Any additional critique?

Comment: seems like an opinion based post... reformat in the form of a non opion-based answerable question?

Comment: I'd say it's a critique question (which is on topic), but the more details you can add, the better. For example, why do you feel the colors are not right? What do you associate blue with?

Comment: I don't agree with @Phlume but it is right on the line. You may want to look at our guidelines and then edit the question further http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions

Comment: I haven't got anything good to contribute except this: have you considered ideas based on the similarity of the WiFi logo shape and a play symbol? Just a thought.

Comment: Oh! Dominic - I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Dominic - I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work in a way that made it clear enough that it was WiFi and a Play button. Shame really, as that's a neat idea.

Comment: Rotate it 45 degrees. It looks too "strict" to me.

Comment: Rotating it 45 degrees works quite nicely, this in conjunction with the gradient and the negative space in the centre should clear things up

Comment: What exactly does wi-fi have to do with the web? I think people are fixating on the CD imagery without really thinking about the desired outcome. The wi-fi logo is loaded with a lot of recognition, very little of which is web-based.

Comment: The first logo reminded me too much of a [power button](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/6/0/5/1194983927973663421io_anthony_liekens_01.svg.med.png) of sorts, but it is much more obvious that the second logo is a disc.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I wouldn't recommend sharing this kinda stuff before its officially part of a product of company. The reason is that people might steal it, and have copyright on it before yours does.

Comment: Because I have created it, it has copyright protection. I would be more worried about someone creating something similar and trademarking it.

Comment: My new favorite icon :-) I like the simplicity, and how good it looks even at smaller sizes. I also like the gradient version submitted by another user, however, yours looks better at smaller sizes whereas the gradient appears unbalanced in icon sizes 64pt and below.

Comment: Thanks, @chazstack - I aligned it with the 16x pixel grid so it'd look good at any scale. I'm quite pleased with the result :D

Answer (score 22):

The WiFi part was immediately obvious to me.  I think what's hurting the recognizability of the CD is the gradient.  If you've looked at other CD renderings, the gradient is angular, not radial.

[image]

via: http://www.psdgraphics.com/psd-icons/psd-compact-disc-cd-icon/

Here's what it might look like with an angle gradient (though I think a couple more color stops might help):

[image]

Comment: Very nice! This solves the gradient weirdness and it's quite subtle.

Comment: I like this idea, actually. I'll see how it looks in different setups.

Comment: This is good - if you can use gradients, I'd suggest it'd be more CD like with an additional angled gradient (maybe light blue?) and slightly sharper edges to the gradients.

Answer (score 11):

I like it! And once I read the post, I completely get the wi-fi + CD. Having said that, I didn't get the CD the first time. About the remote not being there, I think the wi-fi symbol is a clear enough message, I wouldn't change this to include a remote (it would deserve a different question too).

Something I have (very small) *issues* with is the gradient that goes darker as you go up on the wi-fi but sort of around in the CD. I do think it helps with the concept of "information coming out of the symbol", so I would leave the wi-fi as it is and perhaps work a little more on the CD. I'd even check what it looks like with NO gradient for the CD.

Have you considered adding the reflections most cds show? Because you are going for something quite flat, you don't need to create a realistic reflection, I was thinking something like:

[image] [image]

<sub>[Source: Icon Finder](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=cd)</sub>

(Not exactly like the first image, as it actually looks like wi-fi waves :/).

The center of the CDs also have that double circle that is characteristic of them. I'm not sure how or if I would incorporate these, but it's an idea in case someone else mentions the CD might not be as obvious.

Comment: +1 you are going to need a little reflection for the cd. Having said that, is CDs not a little prehistoric these days? ;)

Comment: @boblet I went from cassettes to CDs, then to digital. Yesterday I brought a turntable. So perhaps CDs are ancient, but discs are back, and they have reflections as well, don't they? :D

Comment: I think these are all pretty busy and get the music down really well but I've lost Wi-Fi and still don't have remote control.

Comment: I did rack my brains trying to think of something more modern, but the only thing that came to mind was a cloud, and that'd be far too generic.

Comment: Ah, I was a little unclear: the OP needs some reflection on the blue logo he made, to make it cd-ish. You have the reflections, @Yisela, but missing the wi-fi-remote-thing. Like the turntable, but I am methuselah.

Comment: I think the "reflections" may conflict with the "wiFi" message if both are used and create too much noise on a normally "calm" image. I'd pick one or the other... no both.

Answer (score 6):

> Does this logo effectively portray the product?

Playing devil's advocate: Does it matter?

I'd say, no.

Logos do not have to portray the product in any literal sense--or quite often, any figurative sense. Take the Nike Swoosh. Or IBM initials. Apple Computer.

Point being, don't dwell too much on literal representation. Make sure the logo is relatively unique, works in the context that it will be used in, and doesn't mis-represent the product. Beyond that, it really does come down to aesthetic preferences (both yours, the clients, and hopefully, the end-customers most of all).

Comment: I would disagree, you are comparing a logo for a brand who creates many products to a singular product logo. Bear in mind this is for software and will likely appear on a user's Desktop it is important they create associations. Apple may just be an apple but the iTunes logo is quite clearly to do with music. The manufacturer logo can be ambiguous.

Comment: @George - if you're thinking about an *icon* to represent a product then that implies completely different needs than a *logo*; it seems that this naming is creating some confusion, if a product icon is what you really need instead of a logo?

Comment: @Peteris Poppycock! Evernote, Firefox, IE, Chrome, Skype, uTorrent, Photoshop, Opera, VLC, MS Office... the list goes on, they are all the companies logo. Sure the icons vary system to system but they are all based on the logo. That's just minor semantics, this is software and you are giving advice that is generally bad for software. Hence why software often has its own branding second to the brand that creates it, because it has to be clear and purposeful.

Comment: @George you're making wide sweeping generalizations. An app icon is not the same as a logo. It *can* be, but doesn't *have* to be. And even then, using say chrome as an example, it's clearly not any sort of literal representation of a web browser. There's nothing about the chrome logo that says 'web browser' literally or even figuratively.

Comment: @George - Take a look at your own first example of Evernote - logo https://evernote.com/media/img/logo-new.png vs icon http://www.iphonedriven.com/sites/default/files/evernote-icon.png Of course they share the brand, but they definitely aren't "using their logo as the icon". I'd say it's exactly the opposite! For such software, you focus your branding on building a great **icon** first as the base for their brand, and then derive the logo from that. There are many, many good logos that couldn't ever be used as good app icons; so for software companies you have to keep in mind the difference.

Comment: @DA01 I'm not saying they have to be, nothing has to be anything... we are talking about should bes here. Chrome says web browser because it is the same shape as all the other web browser icons (denoting the world), IE, Firefox, Chrome... think again. You too are making sweeping generalisations based on large brands with huge brand recognition. We have to make generalisations in design, it's a subjective field.

Comment: @Peteris re-read my comment. I said based on and clearly said they differ, which the Evernote conforms to. My point is that the logo should reflect the software's purpose and you have agreed with that by saying base the logo on the icon, seeing as you'd be mad to create an abstract icon without serious brand recognition.

Comment: @George I'm with you...but don't understand how you disagree that logos "do not have to portray the product in any literal sense" and then list of examples that do not portray the product in any literal sense. :)

Comment: As for evernote. It's an elephant. It says *nothing* literal about the product. And that's OK!

Comment: @DA01 True, they do have fantastic brand recognition, that is something this person clearly does not have yet. Although I'm definitely on the figurative side here, software doesn't always have literal representations. I think the issue is that we are showing big well known branded software that is already ingrained in to many people. When you start to look at entry-level software you see they are all pretty much icon representations of the products purpose. I will concede that the icon (including logo) can be abstract but I think you need a large enough user base first, or big marketing money.

Comment: Well, no doubt marketing can always help, but I wouldn't say that you have to have 'brand awareness' before you can go with a non-literal logo. Brand awareness is something that happens (or doesn't happen) often independent of the logo itself. I'd even argue that what's more important is the quality of the style and the uniqueness of the mark. The problem that you often run into with literal logos is that much of your competition may have done the same, ultimately making it that much harder for your brand to stick out and be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

The CD is not reading well. The hole of the CD is the problem. You are using a blue circle as opposed to negative space. I think you need to rework this aspect of your logo.

Comment: I've taken your suggestion and incorporated it into an updated design.

Answer (score 1):

I like it. I think it works based on your concept and goal, and isn't at all too similar to Spotify's logo. Good work.

However, I'm not entirely sure I get "remote control" from it. Without know more about the product its hard to say though. Based on your concept of Wi-Fi combined with a compact disc though I think its very well executed. It certainly gives me music and Wi-Fi.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I would better achieve the "remote" aspect of my design?

Comment: I dont even know what its remote control for so no.

Comment: Well, it's a remote control for a media player.

Comment: My mouse is a remote control for a media player. Is it a mouse? My PS3 has wifi and a media player, are we talking about a PS3 and a new remote for it? Whats it look like? You have some vision and idea in your head but unless you can describe it to us (do so by editing your question not in comments) we have little way to help.

Comment: In which case, the remote itself is an application that runs in your web browser, on your phone or on your tablet that allows you to control the playlist, playback and library management of a media player. Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

'Wi-Fi' is not a synonym of 'the web'.

When I saw that wireless insignia embedded in your logo, I would expect your app to do something to my wi-fi. A new app to connect to wi-fi networks, maybe an app that scans for Access Point information. If I had picked up that it was a CD maybe I would think it is an app that backups my wireless settings to external media.

Basically, my mind's eye immediately thinks 'local networks, it definitely has nothing to do with the internet'.

Comment: It's definitely not a synonym of the Internet, however it is one for "Connectivity", which is what the app is about. I would be more than happy to try and integrate something other than the WiFi logo if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

it's not an iconic shape until it's reducible to a single color for all shapes, lines, etc. the 2 tones indicate conceptual incompletion.  too me, the cd and wifi are not references from the same era. i would challenge you to basically portray 
"media player" aka linear timeline signal flux
and "internet" in a singular shape